# strlen in ASM x64 under Windows and using Nasm

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

My console after execution:

[image: My console after execution]

It's my first request here. I searched a way to fix a bug in my code, but without any success. It's a simple code in Assembly language so as to enter a word (ReadConsoleA), and as an echo, there is loop in order to repeat this word 5 times in the console (WriteConsoleA). At this stage I use a simple integer (16) so as to limit length. The code works as expected, but for an unknown reason, there is a shift after the first iteration. I guess that I could fix it using a function strlen, but I have no clue how I could do that. Do you have an idea? Thank you for your help ++

```
global _start
_start:
    sub rsp, 8
    sub rsp, 32

    mov rcx, STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle

    mov rcx, rax                    
    xor rdx, rdx
    
    mov rdx, input_buffer         
    mov r8, MAX       
    mov r9, written
    mov rax, qword NULL
    mov qword [rsp+32], NULL
    call ReadConsoleA

    xor ebx, ebx            ; at start, ebx is null (for loop)

_loop:
        
    mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle

    mov rcx, rax            ; rcx contains now return value in rax
    lea rdx, [input_buffer]
    mov r8, MAX
    mov r9, written
    mov qword [rsp+32], NULL
    call WriteConsoleA

    inc ebx                 ; ebx++
    cmp ebx, [ECHO]         ; compare ebx with max loop
    jne _loop               ; no? so we continue

    add rsp, 32+8

    xor ecx, ecx
    call ExitProcess
```

Comment: What kind of shift are you talking about?  What output are you getting?  In Windows, is `_start` an actual function that gets called so `rsp+8` is aligned by 16?  (In Linux, the process entry point starts with RSP aligned by 16, unlike functions.)

Comment: Well. I have as output five word, but with a shift (exactly 16 - word.length). I will post a picture. I thing that it could be better. Thank you ++

Comment: Ok. I posted a picture just before my request.

Comment: Run  `x64dbg.exe lol.exe`  and look what data does `rdx` point to before the `call WriteConsoleA`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Finally I found the problem. As I said I cannot use a simple integer so as to set value in R8 (string length). I use a custom function so as to know length and I move it in R8 before calling WriteConsoleA. This way I have no more shifting space.

```
strlen:
    mov rdi, rcx
    xor rax, rax    
    mov rcx, -1
    cld
    repne scasb

    not rcx
    mov rax, rcx
    ret
```

Comment: `ReadConsoleA` has an output operand that can return the number of bytes read. 
 You can use that instead of doing a slow `repne scasb` `strlen`.  See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) `_Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfCharsRead`.

Comment: Interesting explaination. I have to try it. Thank you ++